# How to join multiple cells grouped by values from a second column

Tags: google-sheets

I'm messing with this in Google Sheets.

I have two columns as shown in this image:

[check out columns A and B picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSIQt.png)

I would like to add a 3rd column "C", with joined values from column B depending if they are "Large", "Medium" or "Small".

For example, first cell in my desired 3rd column of joined values from my picture would be: 
10,11,14

Because these values from column B match the same value on column A.

I hope I'm explaining well... I searched before posting here, but I really need a solution for that, and I think I'm missing something.

Comment: Use concrete function with if condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, FILTER($B$2:$B, $A$2:$A="Large"))
```

or, assuming the word 'Large' is in A2:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, FILTER($B$2:$B, $A$2:$A=A2))
```

Comment: Yeah! Thank you!! :S I always forget the Filter option! thanks!

Comment: @tom_sawyer23, most welcome. If this helped, please upvote or accept the answer.